# Numeric data types comparison in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, comparison-operators

Could you please explain the results of the following code:

```
    float f = 1.56898138E+09f;
    double d = 1.56898138E+09;
    int i = 1568981320;

    bool a = f > i; //false 
    bool b = d > i; //true
    bool c = (int)f > i; //true
```

Why is `a == false`?

Comment: float is a 32 bit floating point number, double is a 64 bit floating point number, and int is a 32 bit integer.

Comment: Because `float` is not precise enough to represent `1568981320`. When `1568981320` is converted to `float`, the result is `1568981380`, so `f == i` (`int` is implicitly promoted to `float`, not the other way around). `double` *is* precise enough to represent all possible `int` values exactly, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `int` uses *all* `32` bits to store the integer value

```
 1568981320 == 1011101100001001100000101001000 (binary)
```

when `float` uses `23` bits *only* with first is always `1` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), so
the initial `1011101100001001100000101001000` should be *rounded*:

```
 1011101100001001100000101001000
                         ^ 
 ^                       from this on we should throw the "1001000" bits away
 |   
 this 1 can be skipped since float assumes that the 1st bit is always 1
```

So when rounding we should throw `1001000` away and add `1`:

```
 1011101100001001100000101001000 - original value (1568981320)

 1011101100001001100000110000000 -  rounded value (1568981376)
  ^                     ^
  will be stored in float
```

and this is `1568981376` value which is *bigger* than original `1568981320`

Answer (score 4):

There is an implicit conversion from int to float. This is a rare example of a lossy implicit conversion.

`(float)1568981320 = 1568981376f`, the same value as `f`, so not greater or smaller.